# Python equivalent of npm or rubygems?

Tags: python, rubygems, npm

I've been looking around for a package manager that can be used with python. I want to list project dependencies in a file.

For example ruby uses Gemfile where you can use bundle install.

How can I achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The `pip` tool is becoming the standard in equivalent of Ruby's gems.

Like `distribute`, `pip` uses the [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) package repository (by default) for resolving and downloading dependencies.

`pip` can install dependencies from a file listing project dependencies (called `requirements.txt` by convention):

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can "freeze" the current packages on the Python path using pip as well:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

When used in combination with the `virtualenv` package, you can reliably create project Python environments with a project's required dependencies.

Comment: `pip freeze` created list of all libraries installed in my virtual environment. Is there any way to automatically exclude those that are not necessary for current project to work?

Comment: @Piotrek There's a `-l` (or `--local`) option that may do what your'e asking. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/

Comment: @LXXIII little too late, but thanks anyway ;) I think this particular option deserves to be separate answer. Seems like pretty useful option, which no one knows about.

Comment: Hey, sorry for this silly question but where does requirements.txt goes? :c

Answer (score 52):

## Pipenv

(I know it's an old question, and it already has an answer but for anyone coming here looking for a different answer like me.)

I've found a **very good equivalent for npm**, It's called [**pipenv**](https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv). It handles both **virtualenv and pip requirements at the same time** so it's more like npm.

---

#### Simple Use Case

```
pip install pipenv
```

then you can make a new virtualenv with third version of python, as well as making a **pipfile** that will be filled with your projects requirement and other stuff:

```
pipenv install --three
```

using your created virtualenv:

```
pipenv shell
```

installing a new python package:

```
pipenv install requests
```

running your .py file is like:

```
pipenv run python somefile.py
```

you can find it's doc [here](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/).

Comment: this is the first I heard of pipenv - thanks, this is great

Comment: pipenv doesn't provide all the features provided by npm. It only manages dependecies.

Comment: `poetry` and `pdm` are good alternatives to `pipenv`.

Answer (score 12):

Python uses `pip` for a package manager. The `pip install` command has a `-r <file>` option to install packages from the specified requirements file.

Install command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Example `requirements.txt` contents:

```
Foo >= 1.2
PickyThing <1.6,>1.9,!=1.9.6,<2.0a0,==2.4c1
SomethingWhoseVersionIDontCareAbout
```

See the Requirements Parsing section of the docs for a full description of the format: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

Answer (score 9):

This is how I restrict `pip`'s scope to the current project. It feels like the opposite if you're coming from NodeJS's `npm` or PHP's `composer` where you explicitly specify global installations with `-g` or `--global`.

If you don't already have `virtualenv` installed, then install it globally with:

```
 pip install virtualenv
```

Each Python project should have its own `virtualenv` installation. It's easy to set one up, just `cd` to your project's root and:

```
 python3 -m virtualenv env  # creates env folder with everything you need
```

Activate virtualenv:

```
 source env/bin/activate
```

Now, any interaction with `pip` is contained within your project.

Run `pip install package_name==version` for each of your dependencies. They are installed in `./env/lib/python3.x/site-packages/`

When you want to save your project's dependencies to a file, run:

```
 pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

You actually don't need `-l` or `--local` if you're in an activated project-specific virtualenv (which you should be).

Now, when you want to install your dependencies from `requirements.txt`, set up your virtualenv, and run:

```
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

That's all.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but things are constantly evolving.

Further to the other answer about `pipenv`. There is also a python package manger called `poetry`.

There is a detailed comparison between `pipenv` and `poerty` here: [Feature comparison between npm, pip, pipenv and poetry package managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218592/feature-comparison-between-npm-pip-pipenv-and-poetry-package-managers). It also links the features to common `npm` features.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a comparison of `pipenv` vs `poetry` vs `pdm`: https://dev.to/frostming/a-review-pipenv-vs-poetry-vs-pdm-39b4
The conclusion is that `pdm` is the winner.

But in my experience, `poetry` is easier than `pdm` to integrate with IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

## pip, virtual environment, requirement_list, Pipenv

I wrote an answer in 2021 and it went into all the related details. A thorough TLDR guide. Think worth sharing here.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67650340/7668448

### Resume (check the answer above)

#### Python and pip

- virtual environment
- requirements file (listing of packages)
- pip freeze command
- How to install packages from a requirements file

#### Virtual environment and why

- why
- usage
- Requirement files
- Freeze command
- Installing packages Resume

#### pipenv (The more close to npm)

- Installation
- virtualenv-mapping-caveat
- Basic usage and comparing to npm
- environment management with pipenv
- pipenv run

**The answer includes a thorough TLDR guide. I thought it worth sharing here as well**