# Does python pip have the equivalent of node's package.json?

Tags: python, node.js, npm, pip

In NodeJS's npm you can create a package.json file to track your project dependencies. When you want to install them you just run `npm install` and it looks at your package file and installs them all with that single command.

When distributing my code, does python have an equivalent concept or do I need to tell people in my README to install each dependency like so:

```
pip install package1
pip install package2
```

Before they can use my code?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Once all necessary packages are added

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

creates a requirement file.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

installs those packages again, say during production.

Comment: accepting this as correctly states how to create the requirements file automatically

Comment: This will list all installed packages, not just those used by the project. So if not using inside a virtual environment take care. I don't think there's any way around it though.

Answer (score 33):

The best way may be **pipenv**. I personally use it.

However, in this guide, I'll explain how to do it with just Python and pip. And without pipenv. That's the first part. And it will give us a good understanding about how pipenv works. There is a second part that treat **pipenv**. Check the section **pipenv (The more close to npm)**.

## Python and pip

To get it all well with python. Here the main elements:

- virtual environment
- requirements file (listing of packages)
- pip freeze command
- How to install packages from a requirements file

### Virtual environment and why

Note that for this the package **venv** is to be used. It's the official thing. And shiped with python 3 installation starting from 3.3+ .

To know well the what is it and the why check this out
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

In short, a virtual environment will help us manage an isolated version of python interpreter. And so too installed packages. In this way. Different project will not have to depends on the same packages installation and have to conflict. Read the link above explain and show it well.

> ... This means it may not be possible for one Python installation to meet the requirements of every application. If application A needs version 1.0 of a particular module but application B needs version 2.0, then the requirements are in conflict and installing either version 1.0 or 2.0 will leave one application unable to run.

You may like to check the explanation on **flask framework** doc.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/installation/#virtual-environments

**Why we care about this and should use it**. To isolate the projects. (each have it's environment). And then freeze command will work per project base. Check the last section.

#### Usage

Here a good guide on how to setup and work:

https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Check the installation section first.

Then

To **create a  virtual environment** you go to **your project directory** and run:

On macOS and Linux:

```bash
> python3 -m venv env
```

On Windows:

```
> py -m venv env
```

> Note You should exclude your virtual environment directory from your version control system using `.gitignore` or similar.

To start using the environment in the console, you have to **activate it**

https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#activating-a-virtual-environment

On macOS and Linux:

```
> source env/bin/activate
```

On Windows:

```
> .\env\Scripts\activate
```

See the part on how you check that you are in the environment (using which (linux, unix) or where (windows).

**To deactivate** you use

```
> deactivate
```

### Requirement files

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files

> “Requirements files” are files containing a list of dependencies to be installed using pip install like so

(**How to Install requirements files**)

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

> Requirements files are used to hold the result from pip freeze for the purpose of achieving repeatable installations. In this case, your requirement file **contains a pinned version of everything that was installed** when **pip freeze** was **run**.

```bash
python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Some of the syntax:

```
pkg1
pkg2==2.1.0
pkg3>=1.0,<=2.0
```

== for precise.

```
requests==2.18.4
google-auth==1.1.0
```

Force pip to accept earlier versions

```
ProjectA
ProjectB<1.3
```

Using git with a tag (fixing a bug yourself and not waiting)

```
git+https://myvcs.com/some_dependency@sometag#egg=SomeDependency
```

Again check the link https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files
I picked all the examples from them. You should see the explanations. And details.

For the format details check:  https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/#requirements-file-format

### Freeze command

Pip can export a list of all installed packages and their versions using the freeze comman. At the run of the command. The list of all installed packages in the current environment get listed.

```
pip freeze
```

Which will output something like:

```
cachetools==2.0.1
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
google-auth==1.1.1
idna==2.6
pyasn1==0.3.6
pyasn1-modules==0.1.4
requests==2.18.4
rsa==3.4.2
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
```

We can write that to a requirements file as such

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_freeze/#pip-freeze

### Installing packages Resume

By using venv (virtual environment) for each project. The projects are isolated. And then freeze command will list only the packages installed on that particular environmnent. Which make it by project bases. Freeze command make the listing of the packages at the time of it's run. With the exact versions matching. We generate a requirements file from it (requirements.txt). Which we can add to a project repo. And have the dependencies installed.

The whole can be done in this sense:

Linux/unix

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Windows

```
py -m venv env
.\env\Scripts\activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

First time setup after cloning a repo.

Creating the new env.

Then activating it.

Then installing the needed packages to it.

Otherwise here a complete guide about installing packages using requiremnets files and virtual environment from the official doc: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

This second guide show all well too: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Links listing (already listed):

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/#requirements-file-format
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_freeze/#pip-freeze

## pipenv (The more close to npm)

https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

**pipenv** is a tool that try to be like npm for python. Is a super set of pip.

`pipenv` create virtual environment for us. And manage the dependencies.

A good feature too is the ability to writie packages.json like files. With scripts section too in them.

[Executing pipfile scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519208/executing-pipfile-scripts)

[run python command with alias in command line like npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977743/run-python-command-with-alias-in-command-line-like-npm)

### Installation

https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/

### virtualenv-mapping-caveat

https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/#virtualenv-mapping-caveat

For me having the env created within the project (just like node_modules) should be even the default. Make sure to activate it. By setting the environment variable.

`pipenv` can seems just more convenient.

Mainly managing run scripts is too good to miss on. And a one tool that simplify it all.

### Basic usage and comparison to npm

- https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest
- https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/pipfile/
- https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/
- https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/commands/
- https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/workflows/
- https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/scripts/

Note that the equivalent of npm `package.json` is the **PipFile** file.

An example:

```py
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
flask = "*"
simplejson = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"

[dev-packages]
watchdog = "*"

[scripts]
start = "python -m flask run"

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

There is **Pipfile.lock** like package.lock

To run **npm install equivalent**. You run `pipenv install`.

To install a new package

```bash
pipenv install <package>
```

> This will create a Pipfile if one doesn’t exist. If one does exist, it will automatically be edited with the new package you provided.

Just like with npm.

```bash
$ pipenv install "requests>=1.4"   # will install a version equal or larger than 1.4.0
$ pipenv install "requests<=2.13"  # will install a version equal or lower than 2.13.0
$ pipenv install "requests>2.19"   # will install 2.19.1 but not 2.19.0
```

If the `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1` env variable is set. To make `pipenv` set the virtual environment within the project. Which is created in a directory named **.venv** (equivalent to node_modules).

**Also running **pipenv install** without a PipFile in the directory. Neither a virtual environment. Will create the virtual environment on `.venv` directory (node_modules equiv). And generate a **PipFile** and **Pipfile.lock**.**

[image]

Installing flask example:

```bash
pipenv install flask
```

Installing as a dev dependency

```bash
pipenv install watchdog -d
```

or

```bash
pipenv install watchdog -dev
```

just like with npm.

`pipenv` all commands (pipenv -h)

```bash
Usage: pipenv [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --where                         Output project home information.
  --venv                          Output virtualenv information.
  --py                            Output Python interpreter information.
  --envs                          Output Environment Variable options.
  --rm                            Remove the virtualenv.
  --bare                          Minimal output.
  --man                           Display manpage.
  --support                       Output diagnostic information for use in
                                  GitHub issues.
  --site-packages / --no-site-packages
                                  Enable site-packages for the virtualenv.
                                  [env var: PIPENV_SITE_PACKAGES]
  --python TEXT                   Specify which version of Python virtualenv
                                  should use.
  --clear                         Clears caches (pipenv, pip).  [env var:
                                  PIPENV_CLEAR]
  -q, --quiet                     Quiet mode.
  -v, --verbose                   Verbose mode.
  --pypi-mirror TEXT              Specify a PyPI mirror.
  --version                       Show the version and exit.
  -h, --help                      Show this message and exit.


Usage Examples:
   Create a new project using Python 3.7, specifically:
   $ pipenv --python 3.7

   Remove project virtualenv (inferred from current directory):
   $ pipenv --rm

   Install all dependencies for a project (including dev):
   $ pipenv install --dev

   Create a lockfile containing pre-releases:
   $ pipenv lock --pre

   Show a graph of your installed dependencies:
   $ pipenv graph

   Check your installed dependencies for security vulnerabilities:
   $ pipenv check

   Install a local setup.py into your virtual environment/Pipfile:
   $ pipenv install -e .

   Use a lower-level pip command:
   $ pipenv run pip freeze

Commands:
  check         Checks for PyUp Safety security vulnerabilities and against
                PEP 508 markers provided in Pipfile.
  clean         Uninstalls all packages not specified in Pipfile.lock.
  graph         Displays currently-installed dependency graph information.
  install       Installs provided packages and adds them to Pipfile, or (if no
                packages are given), installs all packages from Pipfile.
  lock          Generates Pipfile.lock.
  open          View a given module in your editor.
  requirements  Generate a requirements.txt from Pipfile.lock.
  run           Spawns a command installed into the virtualenv.
  scripts       Lists scripts in current environment config.
  shell         Spawns a shell within the virtualenv.
  sync          Installs all packages specified in Pipfile.lock.
  uninstall     Uninstalls a provided package and removes it from Pipfile.
  update        Runs lock, then sync.
  upgrade       Resolves provided packages and adds them to Pipfile, or (if no
                packages are given), merges results to Pipfile.lock
  verify        Verify the hash in Pipfile.lock is up-to-date.
```

Command help

```bash
pipenv install -h
```

importing from **requirements.txt**

https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/pipfile/#importing-from-requirements-txt

**Environment management with `pipenv`**

- https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/shell/
- https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/credentials/#injecting-credentials-into-pipfile-via-environment-variables
- https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/configuration/#configuration-with-environment-variables

**`pipenv` run**

To run anything with the project virtual environment you need to use `pipenv run`

As like `pipenv run python server.py`.

**Custom `scripts` shortcuts**

`scripts` in `npm`. Or `tasks`.

https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#custom-script-shortcuts

```py
[scripts]
start = "python -m flask run"
```

And to run

```bash
pipenv run start
```

Just like with npm.

> If you’d like a requirements.txt output of the lockfile, run $ pipenv lock -r. This will include all hashes, however (which is great.). To get a requirements.txt without hashes, use $ pipenv run pip freeze.

**Deployment with pipenv**

- https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#using-pipenv-for-deployments

To mention too the `pipenv cli` rendering is well done:

[image]

Make sure to read the basic guides. And the main [doc link](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), does contains all the links.

And you can see how rich is `pipenv`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because simply `pip install -r requirements.txt` does not compare to the possibilities of the `package.json` at all.

Comment: Author should reconsider how to write.  Ending every sentence with ! is somewhat amusing but also quite distracting.

Comment: Noted. I had that habit. And some people didn't like it. I switched to make all people happy.  (For amusement: ! is like a semicolon, flexed a bit. )

Comment: This answer is so long that we loose track of the important point. I found the section `pipenv (The more close to npm)` in this answer really helpful

Comment: This post has way too many exclamation points to the extent it becomes a distraction. For example you say "In short!", whereas In short should have been followed by a comma.

Comment: @DanielViglione This post is a bit old. I had that bad habit. People pointed me about it. I stopped using exclamations. The links on this post are outdated as well. The official doc changed a bit. I'm counting to update them. So ill profit and remove the exclamation points.

Comment: @DanielViglione it's done. No more !. + All obsolete links are removed and updated for the latest doc. If anything else feel free to edit directly.

Answer (score 12):

Once all the packages have been installed, run

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will save the package details in the file `requirements.txt`.

For installation, run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

to install the packages specified by `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's called the requirements file:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers

You can specify the package name & version number.

You can also specify a git url or a local path.

In the usual case, you would specify the package followed by the version number, e.g.

```
sqlalchemy=1.0.1
```

You can install all the packages specified in a `requirements.txt` file through the command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: What is the `-r` for?

Comment: it specifies that the next argument should be interpreted as a file and not a package to install.

Comment: Above link is broken. This works: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers

Answer (score 2):

I would like to propose *pipenv* here. Managing packages with *Pipenv* is  easier as it manages the list and the versions of packages for you because I think you need to run `pip freeze` command each time you make changes to your packages.

It will need a *Pipfile*. This file will contain all of your required packages and their version just like package.json.

You can delete/update/add projects using `pipenv install/uninstall/update <package>`

This also generates a dependency tree for your project. Just like *package-lock.json*

[Checkout this post on *Pipfiles*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330327/how-are-pipfile-and-pipfile-lock-used#:%7E:text=The%20Pipfile.,currently%20installed%20packages%20using...)

[Learn more about *Pipenv*](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)