# Executing pipfile scripts

Tags: pipenv, pipfile

How can I execute the scripts defined in the Pipfile?

Following the syntax found [here](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/v11.9.0/Pipfile), I defined the scripts section in my pipfile as follows:

```ini
[scripts]
tests = "bash ./run-tests.sh"
```

After running `$ pipenv install`, how can I call the `tests` script?

I've tried the following without success:

`$ tests`

`$ pipenv tests`

`$ pipenv run tests`

`$ pipenv shell (virtual env) $ tests`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem and I happened to solve it thanks to a discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2038).

Long story short, I only updated pipenv *globally* before beginning my project, not *locally*. So I still was using the old version.

To *properly* update the version of `pipenv` that you are using, you have to upgrade `pipenv` also for the user you are using for the project.
Hence :

```
$ sudo pip install pipenv --upgrade --user
```

solved my problem.

May this silly mistake be my first SO contribution, and my eternal shame.

**Edit**:

As noted by [Coleman Stoltze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6837080/coleman-stoltze), the correct way to call the script is :

```sh
$ pipenv run tests
```

Comment: Clarification: the correct way to call the script is `$ pipenv run tests`. There is no need to run `$ pipenv shell`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ pipenv shell 

$ pipenv run tests
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical answer to this would be simply:

```
pipenv run tests
```

---

Your Pipfile's syntax is correct and this is the only way to run scripts.

If `pipenv run tests` don't work, something else is wrong with your setup.

Make sure you at some point have ever run `pipenv install`, you can safely run that again to be sure, or `pipenv update` if you need to lock and sync again.

Also make sure that when you type `pipenv` in your shell you're using the proper pipenv. Some Python setups end up forcing you to call it like one of those following ways:

```bash
$ pipenv
$ python3 -m pipenv
$ pyenv exec python -m pipenv
$ ~/.local/bin/pipenv
```

That happens because most users may and probably have more than one python interpreter, more than one pip, more than one pipenv, and so on, in such a way that you may never know which site-packages and virtualenvs simply typing `pipenv` will give you.

For example, if you issue these commands on Linux:

```bash
$ pip install --user pipenv
$ sudo pip install pipenv
$ python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip pipenv
$ pip3 install pipenv
```

You will have at least two pipenv installations in your system and which one is called when you type in `pipenv` will depend on how your operational system handled those commands and which post installation triggers were performed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what you *are* getting with each of your attempts to help troubleshoot what might be wrong.

https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#custom-script-shortcuts gives a brief introduction to scripts and indicates that your attempt of `pipenv run tests` is the right way to use the script from your Pipfile.

Answer (score 0):

To install packages exactly as specified in Pipfile.lock,
you should run:

```
pipenv sync
```

After that, to keep working in the pipenv, you should run:

```
pipenv shell
```

(Source: https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks, @NicoHaase. I've just updated my answer. Hope it's more helpfu nowl. Cheers!

Comment: and after all of these, can i run with `pipenv tests` ?

Comment: While this is good advice in general, OP's question is about how to run their `tests`  script. The accepted answer is correct (`pipenv run tests`)