# run python command with alias in command line like npm

Tags: python, node.js, npm

In node, you can define a package.json. Then define a `script` block as following:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently -k -r -s first \"yarn test:watch\" \"yarn open:src\" \"yarn lint:watch\"",
  },
```

So in root directory, I can just do `yarn start` to run `concurrently -k -r -s first \"yarn test:watch\" \"yarn open:src\" \"yarn lint:watch\"`

What is the equivalent of that in Python 3? If I want to have a script called `python test` to run `python -m unittest discover -v`

Comment: look into `setup.py test`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use [`make`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)), its great.

create a `Makefile` and add some targets to run specific shell commands:

```
install:
    pip install -r requirements.txt

test:
    python -m unittest discover -v


# and so on, you got the idea
```

run with (assuming that `Makefile` is in the current dir):

```bash
make test
```

NOTE: if you want to run more commands but in the same environment from within a target do this:

```
install:
    source ./venv/bin/activate; \
    pip install -r requirements.txt; \
    echo "do other stuff after in the same environment"
```

the key is the `;\` which puts the commands in a single run and make executes these commands as a single line because of the `;\`. the space in `; \` its just for aesthetics.

Comment: right now i just realised that best answer is the one with pipenv, but `make` its easier to type, to be honest.

Answer (score 13):

Why don't you just use **pipenv**? It is the python's npm and you can add a `[scripts]` very similar to the one of **npm** on your `Pipfile`.

See this other question to discover more: [pipenv stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519208/executing-pipfile-scripts)

Comment: this should be the best answer

Answer (score 6):

Not the best solution really. This totally works if you already familiar with `npm`, but like others have suggested, use makefiles.

Well, this is a work around, but apparently you can just use `npm` if you have it installed. I created a file `package.json` in root directory of python app.

```
{
"name": "fff-connectors",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "fff project to UC Davis",
"directories": {
    "test": "tests"
},
"scripts": {
    "install": "pip install -r requirements.txt",
    "test": "python -m unittest discover -v"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "Leo Qiu",
"license": "ISC"
}
```

then I can just use `npm install` or `yarn install` to install all dependencies, and `yarn test` or `npm test` to run test scripts.

You can also do `preinstall` and `postinstall` hooks. For example, you may need to remove files or create folder structures.

Another benefit is this setup allows you to use any npm libraries like `concurrently`, so you can run multiple files together and etc.

Comment: I don't like this workaround, I mean, should really anyone install npm only to use its scripts functionality and write everything else with python?

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was looking for. My use case is mostly for deploying from local and I work with npm in js components. Therefore this is the solution that will eat less headspace since I can use the same command for deploying both

Answer (score 4):

Answer specifically for tests, create a `setup.py` like this within your package/folder:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='Your app',
      version='1.0',
      description='A nicely tested app',
      packages=[],
      test_suite="test"
      )
```

Files are structured like this:

```
my-package/
  | setup.py
  | test/
  | some_code/
  | some_file.py
```

Then run `python ./setup.py test` to run the tests. You need to install `setuptools` as well (as a default you can use `distutils.core` setup function but it doesn't include much options).