# Feature comparison between npm, pip, pipenv and Poetry package managers

Tags: python, package-managers, pipenv, python-poetry

How do the main features of `npm` compare with `pip`, `pipenv` and [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) package managers? And how do I use those features of `pipenv` or `Poetry`?

This could primarily help someone transitioning from being JavaScript developer to a Python developer.

I've never used [RubyGems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems), but it may also be useful to compare the main features of that to the main Python package managers. To help anyone coming from a Ruby background.

Comment: see [Tried to add a self-answered wiki-post, but just got downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251878/839601)

Comment: It is better to remove all information about `npm` from question and from answer because it is not relevant to Pythonists.

Comment: I can see where you are coming from, but I'm aiming the question and answer at people who are transitioning from javascript to python and might be doing searches like "npm equivalent for python" or "pip vs npm".

Comment: @Resonance  I think your answer is good and useful content, but it would have been better to post directly on an existing question with high visibility such as [Python equivalent of npm or rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13537901/674039) (especially with the current answers there being woefully inadequate)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

## Overview

| Feature \ Package Manager | npm | pip | pipenv | poetry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Access to main repo (i.e. Pypi/npm) | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |
| Record top level dependencies | ✓ | ✗ | Pipfile | pyproject.toml |
| Record development dependencies | ✓ | ✗ | Pipfile | pyproject.toml |
| Lock versions of all dependencies | ✓ | ✓ | Pipfile.lock | poetry.lock |
| Switch between interpreter versions | nvm | ✗ | ✗ | ✓ |
| Direct publishing | ✓ | ✗ | ✓* | ✓ |
| Run scripts | ✓ | ✗ | Pipfile | ✗ |
| Editable local packages | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ | ✓ |
| Integration with Intellij | ✓ | ✓ | partial | ✗ |

* Directly publishing with `pipenv` is possible if using a 3rd party dev dependency, and a script to tie it all together; see below.

Disclaimer: I only have experiences of these packages managers on [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) systems ([OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) in particular), `pipenv` markets itself as treating Windows is a first class citizen, I'm not sure how this works without `pyenv`, which is not available on Windows as far as I am aware.

## Basic Usage

#### pipenv

To get the most out of `pipenv`, `pyenv` should be installed. `pipenv` will be able to detect and use any version of Python installed with `pyenv`, even if it is not activated. For example, if a `Pipfile` has listed Python 3.4 as a requirement: to successfully run `pipenv install`, `pyenv install 3.4.0` should be run first.

To create a new `Pipfile` and [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (using Python 3.7.x):

```
>>> pipenv --python 3.7
```

If you are on linux you may have to use a slightly different command:

```
>>> python3 -m pipenv --python 3.7
```

Or, to install dependencies from an existing `Pipfile.lock`, use the command below. This command can also be used to create a `Pipfile` and venv (defaulting to the newest available Python version).

```
>>> pipenv install
```

To run commands within the created venv:

```
>>> pipenv run <script or command>
```

E.g.,

```
>>> pipenv run python main.py
```

#### Poetry

[Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) still uses `pyenv`, but in a different way: The version of Python you wish to use must be activated before calling `poetry install` or `poetry run`.

A `pyproject.toml` can be created using:

```
>>> poetry init
```

or a full directory structure can be created using:

```
>>> poetry new <dir>
```

Before we can install we must activate a version of Python that matches what is specified in the `pyproject.toml` file.

```
>>> pyenv global <python version specified in pyproject.toml>
```

Now we are able to create the venv using the command below, if a `poetry.lock` file is present it will install all the dependencies listed in it.

```
>>> poetry install
```

To run commands within the created venv:

```
>>> poetry run <command>
```

If we change the global Python version using `pyenv` we will no longer be able to run commands in the created venv. There is an exception to this if we use a locally created venv; see below.

## Running your code using different Python versions

Sometimes it's good to check that your code will work on both Python 3.7 and Python 3.4. This is not something we can take for granted.

#### pipenv

Only possible by deleting the venv in recreating it using a different Python version:

```
>>> rm -rf <path to venv>
>>> pipenv --python <different python version>
```

A warning will likely be displayed that the Python version of the venv does not match the one specified in the `Pipfile`, but as far as I can tell it is only a warning.

*[Multiple parallel environments #1071](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1071)*

#### Poetry

Poetry is much better suited to this use case: Multiple venvs can be created side by side. To create and use a new venv switch Python versions using `pyenv` then create a new venv.

```
>>> pyenv global <different Python version>
>>> poetry install
```

An error will be thrown if the Python version does not match the one specified in the `pyproject.toml` however a range of Python versions can be specified using [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) versioning.

## Local venv

I prefer my venv to be installed in a `.venv` folder local to my project, this is similar to how `npm` works and allows me to delete the folder and reinstall if anything strange happens or if (in the case of pipenv) I want to easily change which version of Python I'm using.

#### pipenv

To enable this feature: set the following environment variable.

```
>>> export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT="enabled"
```

or

Simply create an empty `.venv` folder in the root of your project before creating your pipenv environment.

#### poetry

This feature can be enabled using the following command:

```
>>> poetry config settings.virtualenvs.in-project true
```

But, beware that this will change the behavior of `poetry`: it will no longer be possible to use quickly switch between different versions of Python: Even if the Python version is switched using `pyenv`, all commands run using `poetry run` will use the venv (and its associated Python version) that resides in the local directory.

*[Option to create virtual environments in the project root (.venv) #108](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry/issues/108)*

## Installing Packages

#### pipenv

Packages are easily installed and automatically added to the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files using:

```
>>> pipenv install [--dev] <package name>
```

The `--dev` flag indicates a development dependency. Development dependencies will not be installed by default when using `pipenv install`.

Local packages can also be installed, allowing you to work on them and see your changes immediately:

```
>>> pipenv install -e <path to local package>
```

#### Poetry

Packages are easily installed and automatically added to the `pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock` files using:

```
>>> poetry add [--dev] <package name>
```

The `--dev` flag indicates a development dependency. Development dependencies will not be installed by default when using `poetry install` or added to the package when publishing.

Local packages can also be installed, allowing you to work on them and see your changes immediately:

```
>>> poetry add --path <path to local package> <name of package>
```

I am not sure why the name of the package is needed, as it should already be defined by the local package. Also the author seems unconvinced about linking local packages in general (*[pip install -e . equivalent? #34](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry/issues/34)*) so this feature may get forgotten about over time.

## Running Scripts

To be clear, I'm referring to what `npm` calls scripts, which is different to the scripts specified inside a `setup.py` file.

When developing it is sometimes useful to set up shortcuts for commands that are difficult to remember, for example the command for running every test file in a directory is:

```
>>> python -m unittest discover -s <test_folder> -p '*_test.py'
```

It is much more convenient to have a shortcut to these sorts of commands.

#### pipenv

This feature is supported: put the following into the `Pipfile`:

```
[scripts]
    test = "pipenv run python -m unittest discover -s tests -p '*_test.py'"
```

#### Poetry

Not supported, and unlikely to be added in the future. See [sdispater's comment to *Add tasks #591*](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry/pull/591#issuecomment-504762152).

## Publishing to [PyPI](https://semver.org/)

It would be preferable to be able to publish to PyPI without crafting an additional `setup.py` file, this would be possible if all the information needed to publish the package was contained within the package management files.

#### pipenv

As far as I can tell this is where pipenv gets its bad reputation. `setup.py` files are still needed to publish to PyPi and no, they are not auto-populated with the dependencies from the `Pipfile`.

The recommended approach is to either copy the dependencies over manually when publishing, or to get the Pipfile to install the dependencies listed in the `setup.py` files, however, the `setup.py` is not automatically updated when running `pipenv install <package name>`.

If you really want your `Pipfile` to depend on your `setup.py` file, this is how it's done:

```
>>> pipenv install '-e .'
```

*[Deployment to pypi? #2805](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2805)*, *[Pipenv: A Guide to the New Python Packaging Tool](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/#yes-i-need-to-distribute-my-code-as-a-package)*, and *[How can I integrate with setup.py? #209](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/209)*.

Yuck!

---

So ideally we want to derive a `setup.py` file from the `Pipfile`:

I found two existing packages that claim to do this:

1. *[pipenv-tools](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv-tools/)* - But it hasn't been updated in two years, there's no code in the `src` directory and I couldn't get it to work.
2. *[Pipenv-Setup](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv-setup/)* - But it synchronises the `Pipfile.lock` instead of the `Pipfile`, and this is an antipattern. The lock file is meant for creating a reproducible environment, it is overly restrictive (e.g., by not allowing updates to dependencies) to be used for `setup.py`. For this reason I didn't even try using it.

---

##### My Solution:

I quickly wrote a package that generates an `install_requires.py` file that can be imported in a `setup.py` file: *[pipenv2setup](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv2setup/)* (it is untested on Windows).

For an example of how to use the package when publishing pipenv projects, see this GitHub repository:

*[An example of using pipenv and pipenv2setup to deploy to Pypi](https://github.com/alanbacon/pipenvExample)*

#### Poetry

Publishing your package using Poetry is really easy. You do not need a `setup.py` file at all. Simply run:

```
>>> poetry publish [--build] [--username <username>] [--password <password>]
```

The published package can be installed using `pip`, not just by other instances of Poetry.

For information about how to migrate from using a `setup.py` to purely a `pyproject.toml` file, see here: *[Create and Publish a Python Package with Poetry](https://johnfraney.ca/posts/2019/05/28/create-publish-python-package-poetry/)*

## [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) or [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) integration

#### pipenv

PyCharm is able detect the venv by using the `Piplock` files. However, adding new packages using the PyCharm interface will not modify the `Piplock` files.

#### Poetry

At the time of writing, PyCharm does not seem to be aware of any Poetry virtual environments or appear to parse the `pyproject.toml` file in any way.

## Other points about Poetry

### Semantic versioning

In Poetry you must specify versions of Python and packages using [semantic versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) (have to use `~` and `^`, not `>=`  or `<`).

See *[Semver: Tilde and Caret](https://nodesource.com/blog/semver-tilde-and-caret)*

### Bugginess

Poetry runs using Python, but it doesn't work with older versions of Python. So to develop for an older version of Python: some commands have to be run with `pyenv` set to >3.6, but then the `pyenv` needs to be switched back to the older version to create the venv. It also appears that venvs have to be greater than 3.5.
*[subprocess.run AttributeError occurred in Python 3.4 #1223](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry/issues/1223)*

Also I am not sure about Windows compatibility for Poetry.

## Conclusion

To me the main differences between the `poetry` and `pipenv` lie in their usage of `pyenv` and their abilities (or lack of) to publish straight to PyPI. There is also the lack of scripts in Poetry which I personally find frustrating.

I find that when using Poetry there is a lot more switching between Python environments using `pyenv`. Although currently this can be mitigated by using a locally install venv. I know this limits my ability to quickly test my code in different Python environments, but there are other tools such as `tox` to do that.

Publishing to PyPI using Poetry is so easy, I explained it in one line (above). Publishing to PyPI with `pipenv` is a minefield, to explain it I had to link to an entire Git repository (above).

Comment: I don't understand how the comparison with npm is useful. What's the point of comparing npm (which is a js/node package manager) to Python package managers?

Comment: Mainly to help any javascript developers transitioning to using python. And/or to highlight any missing features of the major python package managers.

Comment: This should really be a blog post. It's way too opinionated and prone to being outdated to be useful in a knowledge library.

Comment: @Arne Can you recommend a blogging platform for a one off post like this?

Comment: @Arne I tried to make it as factual and unopinionated as possible. I challenge your point about it becoming outdated, because I think you could make the same argument for many of the answers on this site, languages and frameworks evolve all the time. There will be lots of answers on here that recommend using deprecated methods and functions.

Comment: [medium](https://medium.com/) is popular for these kinds of posts and gets indexed nicely by google. About opinionated, the question asks for an opinion (hence closed as too broad), so there is not objectivity that a good answer can have. About getting outdated, `poetry` didn't even release a version 1.0 yet and is under active heavy development - no wonder established tools like pycharm haven't picked it up yet. That being said, plenty of people seem to disagree with me, given the vote count on this Q/A.

Comment: oh, I almost forgot. Stackoverflow is also a blogging platform now: https://stackoverflow.blog/

Comment: The poetry config setting should say `poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true`

Comment: Might be better to use `pyenv local` instead of `pyenv global`