# What is the use of having pipenv over pip in an already created virtual environment?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

As far as I know, `pipenv` creates a virtual environment if you are already not working inside one. But if I already have one running, then why use `pipenv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check comparison between pip, pipenv and poetry. Take a look 
[Feature comparison between npm, pip, pipenv and poetry package managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218592/feature-comparison-between-npm-pip-pipenv-and-poetry-package-managers)

In brief for me pipenv and poetry have additional features, like resolving dependencies if two packages depend from another package.