# What causes Python packages installed with pipenv to not be found when called in script?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, pipenv-install, pipx

On a Windows 10 machine with Python 3.9.5 and pipenv 2021.5.29. In a `pipenv shell`:

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: C:\Users\jp\Documents\programming\imseg\Pipfile
Using C:/OSGeo4W/bin/python.exe (3.9.5) to create virtualenv...
[ ===] Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.9.5.final.0-64 in 612ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\jp\.virtualenvs\imseg-cT2t34Fc, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\jp\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.2.2, setuptools==57.4.0, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: C:\Users\jp\.virtualenvs\imseg-cT2t34Fc
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1165]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I used `pipenv install`. This returns:

```
(imseg-cT2t34Fc) C:\Users\jp\Documents\programming\imseg>pipenv install
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (684440)...
  ================================ 19/19 - 00:01:02
```

`pipenv graph`:

```
(imseg-cT2t34Fc) C:\Users\jp\Documents\programming\imseg>pipenv graph
Cython==0.29.24
GitPython==3.1.18
  - gitdb [required: >=4.0.1,<5, installed: 4.0.7]
    - smmap [required: >=3.0.1,<5, installed: 4.0.0]
matplotlib==3.4.2
  - cycler [required: >=0.10, installed: 0.10.0]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.16.0]
  - kiwisolver [required: >=1.0.1, installed: 1.3.1]
  - numpy [required: >=1.16, installed: 1.21.1]
  - pillow [required: >=6.2.0, installed: 8.3.1]
  - pyparsing [required: >=2.2.1, installed: 2.4.7]
  - python-dateutil [required: >=2.7, installed: 2.8.2]
    - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
opencv-python==4.5.3.56
  - numpy [required: >=1.19.3, installed: 1.21.1]
pandas==1.3.1
  - numpy [required: >=1.17.3, installed: 1.21.1]
  - python-dateutil [required: >=2.7.3, installed: 2.8.2]
    - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
  - pytz [required: >=2017.3, installed: 2021.1]
rawpy==0.16.0
  - numpy [required: Any, installed: 1.21.1]
torchvision==0.10.0
  - numpy [required: Any, installed: 1.21.1]
  - pillow [required: >=5.3.0, installed: 8.3.1]
  - torch [required: ==1.9.0, installed: 1.9.0]
    - typing-extensions [required: Any, installed: 3.10.0.0]
```

Yet, when I try to call the script for which the environment was created, I get:

```
(imseg-cT2t34Fc) C:\Users\jp\Documents\programming\imseg\src>python3 model.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jp\Documents\programming\imseg\src\model.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I read and tried

```
pip install pipx
pipx install pipenv
```

and there was no change in the problem. What is wrong with my pipenv environment?

EDIT:
`where python3` returns:

```
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python3.exe
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python3.exe
C:\Users\jp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe
```

EDIT (#2):
It's unclear to me where the python executable is supposed to exist? I guess I don't get the virtual environment thing. If the python executable is supposed to exist in virtual env., why isn't the python executable installed inside the virtual env. to begin? The pipenv website just says to have python and I installed as `pip3 install --user pipenv`, so it seems like it should work. I'm still wondering how to fix this problem.

Comment: try `which python3`, if it doesn't return a path in "C:\Users\jp\.virtualenvs\imseg-cT2t34Fc" then the first python3 in PATH (or maybe some other environmental variable) is not the one you made -- this might be caused by anaconda or another python env manager being initialized after pipenv or some custom PATH entries you've added.

Comment: @AndyP thanks for the suggestion. I get this error: **'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Comment: @John_Polo, my bad, `which` is a unix command.  Windows appears to have a where command -- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. The line that calls the Python executable should be

`pipenv run python model.py`

instead of

`python model.py`

as pointed out in the accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218592/feature-comparison-between-npm-pip-pipenv-and-poetry-package-managers).