# How to switch python3 versions on MacOs

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

I am using python version 3.10.2 but I want to downgrade to 3.9 because it is not compatible with a library in my project. How can I do this with terminal command?

So when I type `python3 --version` my version is 3.10.2 I want to downgrade it. IDE is pycharm

Comment: Personally, I use `conda` (just install miniconda and a virtual environment with python-3.9 for that project). Do no change system interpreter. The operating system may require python 3.10. (so use a parallel version just for your project, and possibly use a different environment for every project). -- PyCharm and conda are well integrated. PyCharm can use many python versions in parallel (also within the same project)

Comment: Depends on what [package manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58218592/10794031) you are using. If you are using and installation of the Python interpreter without virtual environment you'll have to download and install a new Python version. You don't say what kind of venv you are using so there's no way to answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

Install pyenv with Homebrew on macOS:

```
brew update
brew install pyenv
```

Define your vitual env variables:

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
Restart your shell so the path changes take effect

exec "$SHELL"
```

Check the available python versions:

```
pyenv install --list
```

Install the required python version:

```
pyenv install 3.9
```

Set it as your global version:

```
pyenv global 3.9
```

Comment: thank you for your response 
 I do not understand this kind of codes(below). Will I write to terminal? also what should I write for $HOME?


echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
Restart your shell so the path changes take effect

exec "$SHELL"

Comment: I did same thing..

still;

pyenv global 3.9.0......



admin@192 aynam % python3 --version......
Python 3.10.2

Comment: You can also clone the repo to get the latest version of pyenv `git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv'